# Using jScrollPane with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jscrollpane

I installed the `JScrollPane` according to the instructions, and used the body tag as element. However, when I load the page in chrome and IE, there is no scrollbar, not even the default one. In chrome I can still hold the middle mouse button down and drag. Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {
  $('body').jScrollPane();
});
```

Comment: More info !! Paste your code in JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on jscrollpane itself:
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/examples/fullpage_scroll.html

use the example-code and you'll achive what you want:

```
$(function(){
var win = $(window);
// Full body scroll
var isResizing = false;
win.bind(
    'resize',
    function()
    {
        if (!isResizing) {
            isResizing = true;
            var container = $('#full-page-container');
            // Temporarily make the container tiny so it doesn't influence the
            // calculation of the size of the document
            container.css(
                {
                    'width': 1,
                    'height': 1
                }
            );
            // Now make it the size of the window...
            container.css(
                {
                    'width': win.width(),
                    'height': win.height()
                }
            );
            isResizing = false;
            container.jScrollPane(
                {
                    'showArrows': true
                }
            );
        }
    }
).trigger('resize');

// Workaround for known Opera issue which breaks demo (see
// http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/known_issues.html#opera-scrollbar )
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');

// IE calculates the width incorrectly first time round (it
// doesn't count the space used by the native scrollbar) so
// we re-trigger if necessary.
if ($('#full-page-container').width() != win.width()) {
    win.trigger('resize');
}

// Internal scrollpanes
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({showArrows: true});
});
```

Create a div in your body, which contains all data and works as a wrapper.
This div needs the class:    full-page-container

Comment: * This div needs the id: 'full-page-container'